# JPA annotations in entity layer according to Uncle Bob

Tags: java, jpa, design-patterns, architecture

According to [Uncle Bob](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), the entity layer should know nothing about the database.

What about the JPA annotations then? Don't they violate the architecture proposed by the author? If they do, how to use the entities with JPA?

Answer (score 0):

In a non-ORM world, a clean architecture would (or could) involve having DAO interfaces, with DAO implementations knowing how to retrieve the data from a database (or any other source), and convert and return it as a domain object. An upper layer would then use the DAOs (through the interfaces) to retrieve those objects.

This would allow you to for example create different DAO implementations for different databases, and you could change databases without bothering the rest of the software.

In a JPA/ORM world you can bypass a lot of that if you choose. You can use entity classes as domain objects, create the entity classes in a database agnostic way (i.e. not using any database specific `NativeQueries` for example). Now that your entities are database agnostic, you can just use `NamedQueries` in your service layer instead of creating DAOs.

In the end you need to have some layer which knows about the database, but in JPA's case it doesn't even hold true. Your entities are Java objects and it's the JPA implementation layer that is responsible for converting them to and from the database.

In conclusion: there are very few universal truths in software development and you can talk to a dozen uncles and hear a dozen versions of essentially the same "story".

Answer (score 0):

I think that your domain layer should remain free of JPA annotations. In the future, you could replace your JPA implementation by a NoSQL implementation, that would make JPA annotations irrelevant.

Instead of JPA annotations, you could use JPA `orm.xml` in your persistence layer to define your mapping. That would leave your domain layer clean.